# ST_CONTAINS returns false when point inside multipolygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have one point in 4326 and one multipolygon in non-standart srid. I use st_contains function but it returns false. Here is my point and my multipolygon showed in qgis:
[multipolygon (orange) and point (green)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq5g3.png)

Here is my postgres query:

```
select st_contains(geom_of_multipolygon, st_transform(geom_of_point, srid_of_multipolygon));
```

My postgis version is 3.2 and it supports st_contains for multigeometry.

Comment: There is nothing we can do with a png.  Please give us the WKT or WKB for the multipolygon and the point, and value of srid.

Comment: Please add the wkt of both geometries and also the query. I'm afraid you cannot test containment of geometries with two distinct SRS.